# Knowing when a Scripted Patch Request has completed when using UpdateByIndex

Tags: ravendb

If I issue a scripted patch request to my RavenDb via code, is there any way I can discover (with code) if/when the patch request completed?

**Update**
Specifically I use `ScriptedPatchRequest` with `DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex` - and I need to ensure that the patch has completed before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex` returns an instance of `Operation`. You can call `WaitForCompletion()` on this to, uhm, wait for the operation to complete. There's an async version of this method, too, if that's your preferred flavour.

Answer (score 4):

The synchronous `DatabaseCommands.Patch` method blocks until the patch has finished running.

The asynchronous `AsyncDatabaseCommands.PatchAsync` method returns a `Task<RavenJObject>` that is completed when the patch has finished running, and so can be `await`ed.

This way, the client API provides both blocking and non-blocking patch request capabilities. The same goes for all other methods on `DatabaseCommands` and `AsyncDatabaseCommands`.

TBH I do think the behaviour of Patch commands is documented rather poorly... I only figured it out by experimenting.

Comment: Thank you. That's great for patching a single document. However, I often patch entire collections using `DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex` and as far as I can tell that's _not_ blocking. This is really what I need help with - I'll update my question to reflect this.